# "Consent" in passive voice to refer to subject giving consent?

Tags: passive-voice, academia, errors

I noticed a usage I consider odd while copy editing, and I'm hoping someone can explain it. Here are two examples from published academic work:

> Participants **were consented to** the study between 13 July 2009 and 14 February 2013, and randomised between 15 July 2009 and 18 February 2013. ([link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK379254/))

> Thirteen patients **were consented to** the study. ([link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7320091))

Based on the context, I understand them as meaning that the participants consented to the study. However, I find it curious that these samples write in the passive voice rather than the active voice because

- I thought *consent* was only an intransitive verb, which means it can't be passive voice. That's how [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consent) classifies it. To my knowledge, "the researchers consent participants" or "participants consent the study" don't work; "participants consent to the study" does.
- Other verbs could work in the passive voice, like "participants were enrolled in the study." But multiple writers have decided to use this phrasing with *consent*.

My question: Is passive-voice *consent* a trend or something that is approaching accepted usage, a kind of error that happened to make it past some editors, or something that has been long accepted but not noticed?

Comment: I've not met the 'were consented to' structure, but am quite familiar with 'X has been consented' to mean 'X has signed a consent [form]' among NHS staff.

Comment: Yes, for example, hospitals get the patients consented 
 in writing for a surgery.

Answer (score 2):

***To consent a patient*** appears to be medical jargon . . .

> [*A surgeon who fails to consent a patient adequately for an operation
> is in breach of his duty of care to that
> patient.*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2254449/)

You can use scare quotes to signify jargon . . .

> [*Opportunities to "consent" a patient abound on the
> wards.*](http://depts.washington.edu/bhdept/ethics-medicine/bioethics-topics/articles/informed-consent)

If you really don't like jargon, be sure to put an *ugh* after the offending term:

> [*So much is written about informed consent—from how students and
> residents are taught to “consent” a patient (ugh) to the challenging
> of patients’ decision-making capability should they refuse recommended
> treatment.*](https://journalofethics.ama-assn.org/article/less-told-stories-informed-consent/2008-08)

So there's your transitive, jargony verb.

**Active**: *We consented the patients.*

**Passive**: *The patients were consented [by us].*

[It also appears](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22consent+a+patient+to%22) that you can ***consent a patient to*** [something] and ***consent a patient to*** [do something].

.

See also: [When to use scare quotes in formal writing](http://www.languageediting.com/when-to-use-scare-quotes-in-formal-writing/):

> **Use scare quotes to indicate technical jargon**: Scare marks may also signal to the reader that you’re using technical jargon. But
> avoid jargon if you can.

Comment: It is tempting to speculate whether *to consent somebody* is just an equivalent in the medical jargon of *to obtain somebody's consent*, or it expresses the attitude that doing so is merely a formality.

Comment: @jsw29: I wouldn't call consent a formality; [it's a legality](https://studentnotes.themdu.com/issue-archive/issue-1/why-is-patient-consent-important).

Comment: Of course, you wouldn't, nor would I. My point was that those who use *consent* as a transitive verb might be thinking of it that way. Speaking of 'consenting a patient' leaves an impression that this is one of the things that physicians and their staff do to a patient, that the patient is acted upon, rather than acting. This makes one wonder whether they really appreciate that giving or withholding consent is supposed to be a manifestation of the patient's autonomy.

Comment: @jsw29: Ah, yes, I think I see what you mean. *We consented the patient* and *The patient was consented*... Active or passive — the patient's agency is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

A check with Google Books suggests that the passive constructions with “consent”, namely [be/is/was/were consented to](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20consented%20to%2Cbe%20consented%20to%2Cwas%20consented%20to%2Cwere%20consented%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20consented%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbe%20consented%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20consented%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20consented%20to%3B%2Cc0) are on a downtrend rather than on an uptrend, from which probably the fact that they look unusual to today’s readers.